# jQuery .focus() and caret location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering about the behaviour of jQuery's .focus(). I know it sets the focus on an element. But it also seems to place the caret at a place where it was before within that element.

I am not sure if placing the caret is a default, cross browser behaviour of the .focus() function. Nor does the documentation mention this behaviour; https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Any javascript/jquery guru who could shed some light on this?

I would be curious about the javascript that powers the .focus() function. Maybe retrieving that could be a good start for understanding the function better.

Comment: Read the source code, it is open source.

Comment: Read the source like a boss: https://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/